# Error 1050 (Table already exists) when I am creating a new column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a new column in a mysql table using the following command:

ALTER TABLE `PEDIDOS_DETALHE` 
ADD COLUMN `QTD_CAIXAS` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';

When I execute this command, I get the following error:

Error Code: 1050. Table 'magazine/#sql-ib583' already exists

The mysql gives an error in a table with another name.

What is the problem? I didn't understand the error.

Thanks a lot

André

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've got an orphaned temp table.

Have a look at the "Orphaned Intermediate Tables" section in the following link for troubleshooting:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html

> If MySQL crashes in the middle of an ALTER TABLE operation, you may be left with an orphaned intermediate table. Intermediate table names begin with “#sql-”. In your data directory you will see an #sql-*.ibd file and an accompanying #sql-*.frm file with the same name. The intermediate table is also listed in Table Monitor output.
>
> If both the #sql-*.ibd and #sql-*.frm files appear in your data directory, drop the intermediate table by issuing a DROP TABLE statement, enclosing the table name in backticks. For example:
>
> mysql> DROP TABLE `#sql-1291_3`;
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
>
> Enclosing the table name in backticks is required to perform SQL statements on table names with special characters such as “#”.
>
> If there is no table format file (#sql-*.frm file) in your data directory or the DROP TABLE operation fails, create a new .frm file that matches the table schema of the #sql-*.ibd file (it must have the same columns and indexes defined). To do this, perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Determine if the #sql-*.ibd file has a pre-ALTER or post-ALTER schema definition. You can view the columns and indexes of the intermediate table using the Table Monitor.
> 2. Once you have determined if the #sql-*.ibd file has a pre-ALTER or post-ALTER schema definition, create a matching #sql-*.frm file in a different database directory. For example, if an intermediate table has a post-ALTER schema definition, create an .frm file that matches the altered schema definition:
>
>    > mysql> CREATE TABLE tmp LIKE employees.salaries; ALTER TABLE tmp DROP COLUMN to_date;
>    >     Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
>
>    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
>      Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> 3. Copy the .frm file to the database directory where the orphaned table is located and rename it to match the name of the #sql-*.ibd file
>
>    > shell> cp tmp.frm employees/#sql-sql-1291_3.frm
> 4. Drop the intermediate table by issuing a DROP TABLE statement, enclosing the table name in backticks. For example:
>
>    > mysql> DROP TABLE `#sql-1291_3`;
>    >     Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The problem is: my BD is a RDS instance on Amazon AWS and I don't have access to filesystem to do the operations. Is there other alternative? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately it looks a bit dire if you're in AWS: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=562105 - Looks as if cloning your DB or dumping your DB may be the only options.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was missing `ALTER` permission, so I had to grant it like

```
mysql -u root -p
/* type your password */
GRANT ALTER ON yourschema.* TO 'youruser'@'%';
```

Without this permission MySQL Workbench modifies original ALTER query and tries to create my table – and obviously fails as the table already exists.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Method**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS column_name tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0;
```